# PDF not displayed properly when fetched from FTP

Tags: java, pdf, ftp

Im using the following code to fetch a pdf from FTP and display it in the browser. The actual pdf has no issues but when its displayed in the browser, there are some dark pages and blurred charecters only. WHat could be the problem?

```
if (FilePdf != null && FilePdf.length() > 0)
                            {

                                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                        "inline; filename="+fileName);
                                is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(strFile);
                                OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                                byte[] bytesArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                                os.write(bytesArray);
                                os.close();                                 
                                is.close();
                            }
```

Comment: Have you made sure to transfer the file using binary mode? Some FTP server sessions start out in ascii mode...

Comment: retrieveFileStream method is returning an inputStream. How do i make sure of the Binary mode?

Comment: Check my answer on similiar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160004/pdf-looks-empty-in-browser-from-ftp-in-asp-net/38806576#38806576)

Answer (score 1):

Ur right MKL.. This is what did the trick

```
 ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```