# Pdf looks empty in browser from ftp in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to show pdf files in browser which come from ftp. I found some code and I've tried it. The pdf is displayed in the browser but the file is empty. It has all of the pages as the original file but does not have the content on pages.

```
string filename = Request.QueryString["view"];    
FileInfo objFile = new FileInfo(filename);

System.Net.FtpWebRequest request = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + objFile.Name));
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Ftp_Login_Name,Ftp_Login_Password);

System.Net.FtpWebResponse response = (System.Net.FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentEncoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";            
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Request.QueryString["name"]);
Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
Response.End();
```

How can I show it in the browser correctly?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8weMr.png

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FileInfo objFile = new FileInfo(filename);
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + filename));
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Ftp_Login_Name, Ftp_Login_Password);

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

byte[] bytes = null;
using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
    bytes = memstream.ToArray();
}

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + objFile.Name);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
```

Comment: thank you, this saved me days headache... specifaclly to get the correct byte array i had to use this code: byte[] bytes = null;
using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
    bytes = memstream.ToArray();
}

Answer (score 0):

[`Response.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585(v=vs.90).aspx) is used for sending text to the client. A PDF file contains binary content so the content may be converted incorrectly.

Use [`Response.BinaryWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524318(v=vs.90).aspx) instead. Additionally in your code, you are not sending the file. Try this:

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);

int length = (int)fs.Length;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(length);

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentEncoding = reader.CurrentEncoding;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";            
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Request.QueryString["name"]);
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Comment: With `Response.BinaryWrite` which code should I use, I cannot use `reader.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: That code makes no sense, you are trying to use the response stream to write output from?

Comment: How can I do that? I do not know, it's not the code which I wrote full. 
How can I get the file from ftp then show it in the browser, without asking to save?

Comment: what should I write instead of this, `File.OpenRead(filename)` ?